# What UML diagram should be used for modelling permissions/users/files in Linux?

Tags: testing, linux, uml

If I am planning a structure for support testing in Linux, a structure that will contain packages, such files as shell and build scripts, app configurations, DBs, sources, tests and jars for to be managed, applications for be managers, users, permissions, etc., what diagram could be used for it? Just now I am using the Component Diagram with some stereotyping, but it is not at all convenient in the part of permissions/users stuff. There are such diagrams as [RBAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control), but they are not UML, and it remains unclear how to combine them.

An example picture and/or a real experience description would be highly appreciated. But any fresh thought will be useful, too.

Comment: Related: [How to Model a simple file-system by UML class diagram](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/146286/25936)

Comment: @YannisRizos I am afraid that the system in this case is extremely far from being simple. And any error in permission politics in one single file will cause all the system to fail. And in your example there is not a word on permissions at all.

Answer (score 1):

I donot think that there is a good uml-diagram type to model this.

The best (but in my opinion still inapropriate) diagram i can think of is a [use case diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_Case) where the [Actor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_%28UML%29) can be considered as a role with certain permissions.

Use_Casees are from business-point-of-view while asking for "linux" or "file" is asking from technical-point-of-view.

Comment: The problem is, that I have a set of objects and packages. And the rights are applied to them. So, according to you, I should use Use Case diag for actor figure only, but mostly use elements from component/package/class/object diagrams.

Comment: The objects and packages are proxies for the actors that carry out the operations. Treat them as augmentations of the actor in the use cases.

Answer (score -4):

I think you would need more than one UML diagarams to model.

Package and component diagram to model the app, config, db etc...

Use case diagram to model the authorization and authentication part.

Comment: This isn't a poll; explain what *else* is needed, don't just posit an opinion.